# Rails - Where :created_at less (older) than self.created_at (Mongoid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

(I've seen all related questions about this but none of them have worked for me)

On `before_update`, I need to fetch the last record before ***self*** but can't figure out how to query "`created_at < self.created_at`". I'm trying this:

```
def set_update_consumo
    lastRecord = 
       Reporte.where(:hidrometro_id => self.hidrometro_id)
      .where('created_at < ?', self.created_at)
      .order_by(:created_at => 'desc').offset(1).first

    set_record(lastRecord)
end
```

And I get this error:

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 784ms
>
> **ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))**:
>
> app/models/reporte.rb:49:in 'set_update_consumo'
>
> app/controllers/reportes_controller.rb:57:in `block in update'
>
> app/controllers/reportes_controller.rb:56:in `update'

If I delete `where('created_at < ?', self.created_at)` it works. None of the other answers in SO have worked for me, and can't use gems (like squeel).

I'm using Rails 5.0.2 (Ruby 2.4) with ***Mongoid***.

Comment: do you have any method named `created_at`?

Comment: you are using ActiveRecord and not Mongoid right?

Comment: can you paste at least a few lines from the stack trace of the error?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon yes, created_at of Mongoid Timestamps.

Comment: @max Mongoid, sorry I didn't mentioned

Comment: Don't know, but can/did you try this? `.where("created_at < #{self.created_at}")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mongoid, the `where` syntax is a bit different from ActiveRecord and indeed takes only a single parameter - a hash. For a "less-than" expression you need to use the `.lt` method on the attribute symbol:

```
where(:created_at.lt => self.created_at)
```

See the [docs](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html) for more info.

Furthermore, you probably don't have to use `self` here and simple `created_at` should give the same result.

Comment: Can't believe didn't check Mongo docs before.. worked as expected, thanks!